# QPdfDocument/QPdfView: How to display an animated PDF?

Tags: c++, qt

I implemented a PDF Viewing widget in C++ using Qt, loosely based on https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtpdf-pdfviewer-example.html, using the pdfwidgets module. (For this question, we can assume that I copied the code in that link 1:1).
This works well so far.

But now the thing is, the PDF I want to display happens to be an animated PDF. Opened in a regular viewer like Acrobat, it will show a short sequence. That sequence is located on a single page, the frames are not different slides.

In the documentation of the [QPdfDocument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpdfdocument.html) and the [QPdfPageNavigation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpdfpagenavigation.html) classes, I can't find any functionality that deals with animated pages. It would suffice if I had any way to set the current animation phase.

Is this possible at all? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not implemented at the moment. On Windows, you could use an ActiveQt widget to embed Acrobat Reader inside your application, if present. Otherwise you'd need to find a PDF rendering library - most likely a commercial one - that has such support.